# How to resolve choice between string and struct datatype in AWS Glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, struct, types

I have this field raw_response which has two different data_types (that's why is detected as choice in AWS Glue):
string and struct, now I would like to move the string field inside the struct field, specifically to the raw_response subfield inside the struct (in the subset of records that raw_response is detected as string).

```
|-- hooks: array
|    |-- element: struct
|    |    |-- updated_at: string
|    |    |-- response: struct
|    |    |    |-- code: string
|    |    |    |-- raw_response: choice
|    |    |    |    |-- string
|    |    |    |    |-- struct
|    |    |    |    |    |-- status_code: int
|    |    |    |    |    |-- code: string
|    |    |    |    |    |-- raw_response: string
|    |    |    |    |    |-- message: string
|    |    |    |    |    |-- data: struct
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- order_id: string
|    |    |    |    |    |-- status: string
|    |    |    |    |    |-- string: string
|    |    |    |    |    |-- struct: struct
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- data: struct
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- order_id: string
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- status: string
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- status_code: int
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- code: string
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- raw_response: string
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- message: string
|    |    |    |-- message: string
|    |    |    |-- http_status_code: int
```

How could I do this? I know the use of ResolveChoice when there are simple datatypes(string, int) but for complex datatypes I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the numeric rather than the string version of the price by setting the path to "myList[].price", and setting the action to "cast:double".

Comment: Sorry, i did not understand your answer, also consider that my field is inside an array, and i want to move ```hooks(element.response.raw_response(string))``` --> ```hooks(element.response.raw_response(struct).raw_response(string))```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).